# How to set the Place Holder for TextArea in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I need to show the place holder for the Text Area Field, so can you tell me how to set the Place Holder for Text Area in Codename One.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextArea myTextArea = new TextArea();
myTextArea.setHint("My placeholder text");
```

Comment: Provide more context to this answer, a single line of code by itself isn't helpful.

Comment: @Adam Read the question.  If you still don't understand the answer or find that it is unhelpful, please provide constructive advice on what could be added or removed to make it more clear.

Comment: @stevehannah: the question is so brief it is tempting to vote as off-topic. The OP seems to be posting a stream of low-effort questions of this kind - is that normal for this tag? In general if no effort has been made I tend not to answer (though it is up to each answerer, of course).

Comment: @Adam It's all over the map (as far as questions being low effort).    While the OP could have learned this information in the javadocs, it isn't uncommon to just "ask".  SO is the preferred community support channel for CN1, so there may be many questions like this one by people who just have an API related question.

Comment: My main concern is that you don't provide context to your answer. What is `myTextArea` and how is it defined? An ideal answer would be a self-contained code block that could execute without errors (within reason). You could also quote the docs to provide more explanation (if there is any). I guess my point is, low-effort questions don't deserve low-effort answers in return.

Comment: I added some context now to clarify that `myTextArea` is a `TextArea` in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField xyz = new TextField("", "xyz", 25, TextArea.ANY);
```